# setting custom Row Source in ComboBox OnChanged, added records not saving

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a Customer form with an Orders subform, and there is a one-to-many relationship between Customer  and Orders.  This subform is in Datasheet view and is editable, so a user of the access application can add Orders to a Customer .  The Orders being added to the subform must match one of the entries in the Orders table.  All in all, this is a fairly standard Form-Subform setup.  When the user is done adding Orders to a Customer, he closes the form and the order is automatically saved to the intersection table between Customer and Order.  Note that this combo box has a Row Source property something like

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_NAME from ORDERS;
```

This all works fine.

Now, if I modify the Combo Box in the Datasheet to have no Row Source property, and dynamically set the RowSource equal to a custom SQL query in the OnChanged event of the Combo Box, I can get the custom filtering of options in the combo box that I am looking for.  However, when the user saves and closes the form, the link between the Customer and Order that was entered into the subform is not saved to my intersection table.

So, my problem seems to be that changing the Row Source from a static property to something dynamically changed in SQL prevents the user from saving the Orders they add to a Customer.  This is the only change I am making.  Once made, the additions made to the subform stop saving to my intersection table.

The SQL string I am setting the Row Source property of the Combo Box to in OnChanged is something like this VBA code:

```
Dim comboText
comboText = Me.OrdersComboBox.Text

Me.OrdersComboBox.RowSource = "SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_NAME FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_NAME LIKE '*" & comboText & "*' OR ORDER_SHORTNAME LIKE '*" & comboText & "*';"
```

Basically, I'm just trying to improve the autocomplete functionality of the combo box by allowing the user to search the Orders table against the full order Name or the order ShortName.

However, I can't get the additions to the datasheet to save when I'm setting the Row Source of the Combo Box in OnChanged.   Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this and cannot replicate the issue. Code works for me. How do you commit records? By just moving to another row?

Comment: Yes, by selecting the next row in the Datasheet on the subform, I'm able to commit records.  Those commits save when the Row Source is set as a property, but do not save when I set the Row Source in VBA.